# Tetrahedron and balls in space

Tags: general-topology, geometry

A right tetrahedron and a ball arbitrarily located in space are given. It is allowed to reflect the tetrahedron from each of its faces. It is possible to place the center of the tetrahedron inside the ball utilizing such transformations?